# How many units will fit in the window and push that value to an array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, break

Please Look at my:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matty0187/5v5abqzq/1/)

I have a dataset and I want to push a new value to the array.

This value is determined by a sum of an accumulated size is less than the windowSize.

**Updated:**
In the end I'm trying to create a group of offsets. I thought By calculating how many data[i].size.updated.width will fit into the current window.innerWidth, I can know how far to translate a element. To do this, Once the tempGroupSize is Greater than the WindowWidth, I need to push that offset to the data[i].pageGroup. And Then move to the next data[i] and repeat the process.

This maybe easier if done with lo-dash? (i'm pretty novice with this)

The final data should look something like:

```
 var data = [{
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 2000
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 718.9359467973399,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    //this is value is an example of the windowwidth > 1436 but less than 2154(3 pages)
    "pageGroup": [1436]
},
```

//this will repeat for every index because the dataset has all the same sizes
**.end of update**

I'm iterating through ever page twice so that I can push a this size per page group `data[i].pageGroup.push(tempGroupSize);`

**Problem:**
When I break; it seems that the both loops stop.

**Question:**

How would I get this loop to continue until  `for i` has been completed?

**Caveat:**

I must return `currentBreakPage` to make sure i don't iterate over pages that are already grouped

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var k = currentBreakPage; k < data.length; k++){
        //makes sure it's not the first time through
        if(currentBreakPage === 0){
           // console.log('break is:', 0);
            iterator = data[i].size.updated.width;
            //console.log(iterator);
        } else {
            //console.log('break is else:', currentBreakPage);
            iterator = data[currentBreakPage].size.updated.width
        }
        //iterator must be subtracted because we dont want to count the most current page in the the total window size;
        if(tempGroupSize < (windowWidth -  iterator)){
            tempGroupSize += data[k].size.updated.width;
        } else {
            currentBreakPage = k;
            data[i].pageGroup.push(tempGroupSize);

            break;
        }
    }
    console.log('pageGrooup', currentBreakPage)
}
```

Comment: my answer shows that `for i` is completing.  Your `currentBreakPage` never advances once the `if(tempGroupSize < (windowWidth -  iterator)){` condition fails for the first time-- it's really `k` that never does anything after the first or second (or none!) run-through.

Comment: yeah I think my approch is wrong.  I feel like I'm overcomplicating a rather simple problem.

Comment: do you need to reset `tempGroupSize` to 0 after you push it onto the pageGroup?  i.e., after `data[i].pageGroup.push(tempGroupSize);`

Comment: Yes it should be reset to 0 because it's a new group at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to give you an idea of what's happening.  I fixed some missing semicolons and converted the code to log to a `<div>` in the fiddle window. http://jsfiddle.net/5v5abqzq/3/

It looks like your math is just not what you expect.  The first loop through sets the `tempGroupSize` value, but every loop after that winds up resetting the `currentBreakPage` back to 0.

Just running this code in the SO Snippet window always returns a negative number for `windowWidth - iterator`, so the code will always set `k = currentBreakPage;` which means `k = 0`.  Your `for` loop always sets `var k = currentBreakPage`, so you are creating an endless loop depending on your window size.

When I ran this as a jsfiddle, I did get a larger number, but then `currentBreakPage` would be stuck at `1` because of this code always evaluating to false: `if(tempGroupSize < (windowWidth -  iterator)){`

**Check your algorithm and math, and verify what you are trying to do.**

**EDIT: Here's the new fiddle.  I updated the `tempGroupSize = 0;`: http://jsfiddle.net/5v5abqzq/6/

```js
var logger = {
    log: function (text){
        var _console = document.getElementById('console');
        _console.innerHTML = _console.innerHTML + '<br />' + text;
    }
};

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var tempGroupSize = 0,
    currentBreakPage = 0,
    iterator = '';
logger.log('win' + windowWidth);
var data = [{
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 100
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 10,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 200
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 2000
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 200
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 100
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 50,
            "height": 50,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 300
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 400
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}, {
    "size": {
        "original": {
            "height": 2857,
            "width": 500
        },
        "updated": {
            "width": 200,
            "height": 1027,
            "isPortrait": false
        }
    },
    "ratio": 0.7000350017500875,
    "pageGroup": []
}];
logger.log(data.length);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var k = currentBreakPage; k < data.length; k++){
        
        if(currentBreakPage === 0){
           // console.log('break is:', 0);
            iterator = data[i].size.updated.width;
            logger.log(iterator);
            //console.log(iterator);
        } else {
            //console.log('break is else:', currentBreakPage);
            iterator = data[currentBreakPage].size.updated.width
            logger.log('currentBreakPage: ' + currentBreakPage);
        }
        
        logger.log('tempGroupSize: ' + tempGroupSize + ', (windowWidth - iterator): ' + (windowWidth - iterator) + ', result: ' + (tempGroupSize < (windowWidth -  iterator)) );
        
        if(tempGroupSize < (windowWidth -  iterator)){
            tempGroupSize += data[k].size.updated.width;

            logger.log('setting temp group size to ' + tempGroupSize);         
            
        } else {
            
            currentBreakPage = k;
            logger.log('currentBreakPage: ' + currentBreakPage);
            data[i].pageGroup.push(tempGroupSize);
            tempGroupSize = 0;
            
            break;
        }
    
       
        
    }
    logger.log('pageGroup' + currentBreakPage);
}
```

```html
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: In the end I'm trying to create a  group of offsets. By calculating how many data[i] will fit into the current window.innerWidth, I can know how far to translate a element.  Once the tempGropuSize is Greater than the WindowWidth, I need to push that offset to the data[i].pageGroup. And Then move to the next data[i] and repeat the process.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, I updated the code snippet and the jsfiddle.  Some of your data values for window width is too large for the fiddle to work properly, and all are too large for the SO snippet to work properly.  I've changed the code snippet here to use much smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

Change `break` to be `k = data.length`

If you ever want to stop a loop, just make your iterator go out of bounds so it doesn't go through the loop again.

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but it still doesnt seem to be running the outer loop after i break the inner loop.  in the end, pageGroup to be a single value of a page grouping. depending on screen resolution it should be a value of 718 or 1436.

Comment: @MatthewHardwood Yeah the other answer ps2goat posted goes into more detail. In a nutshell, it seems you are never actually hitting the first if and always hitting the else because `windowWidth-iterator` always returns negative. Even though the loop is cancelling, currentBreakPage never actually changes value (it always remains 0). Not sure what you are trying to achieve so if you update your question, perhaps people can help with that. But I assure you that this is how you break out of your loop :P

Comment: Hey man I updated teh question with maybe a more concise question.  Could you perhaps check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Well `break` just exits the loop in which it is present

```
for(j=0;j<val1;j++)
{
for(k=0;k<val2;k++)
{
if(condition)
break;
}
//after break you will be here in second loop
}
```