# Iterating through an array and sum a value based on a condition in lo-dash

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, underscore.js, lodash

I have a data set which i've simplified :

```
var data = [{
    size: 400
}, {
    size: 500
}, {
    size: 800
}, {
    size: 400
}, {
    size: 400
} {
    size: 300
}, {
    size: 300
}, {
    size: 800
}];
var windowWidth = 800;
```

Using lo-dash how would I make a new array based on how many of size would fit into windowWidth.
the preferedfinal dataset will look like this

```
var newArray = [{
            group: [0],
            size: 400
        }, {
            group: [1],
            size: 500
        }, {
            group: [2],
            size: 800
        }, {
            group: [3, 4],
            size: 800
        }, {
            group: [5,6],
            size: 600
        }, {

            group: [7],
            size: 800,
        }
```

The key `group` refers to  the indexes of `data[n]` that meet the condition of lessthan windowwidth. 
 the key `size` refers to the accumulated size of the group.

Note: `data[n]` just counts up and doesnt repeat for ever go back to data[0].

does `data[n]` fit inside window? 
   yes? push to group; go to `data[n +1 ].size`; check expression

no?  create new group(); go to data[n +1].size; check expression

Comment: _"based on how many of size would fit into windowWidth"_? What? How exactly is the result supposed to be calculated from the source?

Comment: if(tempAccumlatedSize < windowWidth){...}?  i'm not too sure if this is even possible.  I've done it in a very confusing nested forloops that force breaks lol.  I can link the question to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751236/how-many-units-will-fit-in-the-window-and-push-that-value-to-an-array heres the same question done in forloops

Comment: I still don't understand what's supposed to happen to the input array. Please add a exact explanation of what `group` and `size` mean, in that result.

Comment: Are you only combining items in array order?  In other words you would not match item at index 0 (size:400) with item at index 3 (also size:400) since they could be <= 800.

Comment: Thats corect @MikeBrant in order do not repeat

Comment: I'll write the logic above to explain better

Comment: @MatthewHarwood What is items is greater than 800? Without regards to underscore or lo-dash, do you understand the basic algorithm that you are going to apply? In other words do you know what you would write in plain javascript or pseudo-code? Just trying to understand if this is really a lo-dash problem or an algorithm problem.

Comment: I've added the logic above.  I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = _.chain(data).pluck('size').reduce(function(result, val, i) {    
    if (_.isEmpty(result) || val + _.last(result).size > windowWidth)
        result.push({ size: val, groups: [i] });
    else
    {
        var last = _.last(result);
        last.size += val;
        last.groups = last.groups || [];
        last.groups.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}, []).value();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/219g9hqm/**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured out what you need:

```js
var data = [{size: 400}, {size: 500}, {size: 800}, {size: 400}, {size: 400}, {size: 300}, {size: 300}, {size: 800}],
    newArray = [],
    prevSize = 0,
    lastIndex,
    windowWidth = 800;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    lastIndex = newArray.length - 1;
    if(prevSize == data[i].size && (newArray[lastIndex].size + data[i].size < windowWidth)){
        newArray[lastIndex].group.push(i);
        newArray[lastIndex].size += data[i].size;
    }else{
        prevSize = data[i].size;
        newArray.push({group:[i], size: data[i].size});
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
alert(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Comment: Except it's not using lo-dash :)

Comment: Cerbrus previous size will always be a static number like 800 could you rewrite this with that in mind?

Comment: Your right I think this is the better alternative. I thought it would be easier using lo dash but this is rather readable

Comment: @Cerbrus what if the first 3 index sizes were 200? Would that yield{group:[0,1,2],size:600 } ? On my phone just don't want to lose you

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: Yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best approach but it only uses lodash functions:

```
var indexed = _.map(data, function (e, i) {
  e['index'] = i;
  return e
});
var grouped = _.groupBy(indexed, function (e) {
  return e.size
});
var newArray = _.map(grouped, function (e, key) {
  return {'size': key, 'group': _.pluck(e, 'index')}
});
```

### Version 2

A less inefficient version using `_.reduce` for the grouping and `_.map` for transforming the grouped object into a list of objects. Filters out all the sizes greater than `windowWidth`.

```
var windowWidth = 400;
var grouped = _.reduce(data, function (result, e, i) {
  if (e.size <= windowWidth) {
    var group = result[e.size];
    if (!group) {
      group = result[e.size] = [];
    }
    group.push(i)
  }
  return result;
}, {});
var newArray = _.map(grouped, function (e, key) {
  return {'size': key, 'group': e}
});
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezwh57pp/6/)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yep, I know at most 4 times. It is just an attempt/exercise to do it using only lodash functions. Not pretending to be the optimal :).